# TabLayoutPanel has no method called setAnimationDuration()

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm reading the official tutorial on how to use `TabLayoutPanel` but I'm facing a problem; 
The `TabLayoutPanel` has no method called `setAnimationDuration()` as is mentioned in the tutorial.

Anyone has an idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabLayoutPanel` has method [`setAnimationDuration`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#setAnimationDuration%28int%29) in GWT version 2.3.